# DataGrid in a TreeView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, treeview

I am trying to bind to a collection of `StringValue` objects in a `DataGrid`, but each item is displayed in a separate row. I want to have a columnar display, where values like `565477` and `65656` are displayed in the same row. Here is my current code:

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Warnings">
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding WarningCategories}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Warnings}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Category}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HeadersVisibility="None">
                            </DataGrid>                                
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
   public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public ObservableCollection<WarningCategory> WarningCategories { get; set; }


      public ViewModel()
      {
         WarningCategories = new ObservableCollection<WarningCategory>();

         ObservableCollection<Warning> warnings = new ObservableCollection<Warning>
         {
            new Warning( new StringValue("565477"), new StringValue("65656")),
            new Warning( new StringValue("767455"), new StringValue("75642")),
         };


         WarningCategories.Add(new WarningCategory("Warning One", warnings));



         warnings = new ObservableCollection<Warning>
         {
            new Warning( new StringValue("565477"), new StringValue("65656")),
            new Warning( new StringValue("767455"), new StringValue("75642")),
         };



         WarningCategories.Add(new WarningCategory("Warning Two", warnings));
      }



      [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
         var handler = PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }

   public class WarningCategory
   {
      public string Category { get; set; }

      private ObservableCollection<Warning> m_warnings;

      public ObservableCollection<Warning> Warnings

      {
         get
         {
            return m_warnings ?? (m_warnings = new ObservableCollection<Warning>());
         }
      }


      public WarningCategory(string category, ObservableCollection<Warning> animals)

      {
         Category = category;

         m_warnings = animals;
      }
   }

   public class Warning

   {
      public ObservableCollection<StringValue> Fields { get; set; }

      public Warning(params StringValue[] fields)

      {
         Fields = new ObservableCollection<StringValue>(fields);
      }
   }

   public class StringValue
   {
      public StringValue(string s)
      {
         Value = s;
      }
      public string Value { get; set; }
   }
```

The result I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

I have a workaround, but it does not support multiselection. Here is the code for this workaround:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Width="150"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I achieve the columnar display I want using a `DataGrid` and maintain support for multiselection?

Comment: Do you actually want to ever have multiple rows in the data grid?  Why are you using a data grid at all?

Comment: @DanField No actually. But i want to be able to select the full row. I found that functuality in DataGrid-

Comment: Could you add something to your post showing what you expect the final output to look like?

Comment: @DanField I added.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you want to multi-select now - individual values? rows? both?

Comment: When the user clicks or hovers he should be able to select the whole row. If he holds ctrl he should be able to multiselect the rows.

Answer (score 1):

instead of DataGrid (which can be pivoted, but it is problematic) use ListBox with horizontal StackPanel for ItemsPanel

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>     

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
                    Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataTemplate>
```

to enable full-row select I created binding of ListBoxItem.IsSelected to TreeViewItem.IsSelected

Comment: Thanks Ash, I want to be able to select the whole row.

Comment: Thanks. It works but only when I click a cell the whole row is selected., on hover only a single cell is selected.

Comment: @Vahid, do you need to select individual values? or always full-row? if always full-row, replace ListBox with ItemsControl (and remove ItemContainerStyle). ItemsControl doesn't support selection of items

Comment: I want to be able to multiselect rows.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise against a `DataGrid`, and I'd also rework the way your templates are working currently.  Something like this is pretty close to what you want, I think:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WarningCategory}" ItemsSource="{Binding Warnings}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Category}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Extended">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldsPivoted}" />
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <!--<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Warning}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FieldsPivoted}"    />
        </DataTemplate>-->
    </TreeView.Resources>

    <TreeViewItem Header="Warnings" ItemsSource="{Binding WarningCategories}" />
</TreeView>
```

With this added to your `Warning` class:

```
public string FieldsPivoted
{
    get
    {
        return string.Join(", ", Fields.Select(x => x.Value));
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Using a list should allow for multiple selection the way you're looking for.

Comment: Dan , I'm using a similar method now, but unfortunately that does not solve my problem. Please see my edit:

Comment: Edited - it now has a listbox in there that allows for multiple row selection.

Comment: thanks Dan, Can you please upload the picture. I'm missing something. I just can select one row now.

Comment: it is great! But I think something is a bit wrong. When you click it just selects. Without holding the control which is the default behavior of the listboxes-

Answer (score -1):

Create a new class which you would use for the databinding.

CLASS

```
Public class MainClass
{
    public void MainClass(string row,string rowValue)
    {
        Row = row;
        RowValue= rowValue;
    }
  public string Row
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string RowValue
  {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

VIEWMODEL

```
        private ObservableCollection<MainClass> _mainClassList = new ObservableCollection<MainClass>();
        public ObservableCollection<MainClass> MainClassList
        {
            get { return _mainClassList; }
            set
            {
                _mainClassList= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.MainClassList);
            }
        }
        public void AddItems()
        {
         _mainClassList.Add(new MainClass("row1","row1Value"))
         _mainClassList.Add(new MainClass("row2","row2Value"))
         MainClassList = _mainClassList;
        }
```

XAML

```
 <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" RowHeight="23" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MainClassList}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="70*" Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Row,Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="70*" Header="Column2" Binding="{Binding RowValue,Mode=OneWay}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: What is Column1Value?

Comment: @Vahid it works and does exactly what you wanted it to do, why downvote ?